# Programmatically change clearTaskOnLaunch

Tags: android-activity, android-manifest, android

Currently incorporating other forms of login to my application(facebook, etc), which retain session information differently than my native login. Currently doing some testing in memory constrained conditions, where the application will be freed to release the resources; when this happens I would like to clear the back stack so that the user won't be returned to an activity in an invalid state and will be returned to the login activity, but only for users who are logged in via authentication from a third party service(with the native login the state can be restored fine).

I know you can clear the back stack by setting clearTaskOnLaunch to true in the manifest, however, I would like to be able to change the value at run time(depending on their login method), but was unable to find anything on here or the developer site suggesting that clearTaskOnLaunch was accessible via the java code. Any ideas?

Note, I plan on making the state information restore more elegantly for third party registration in the future, this is just the "good enough" solution for the time being.

Comment: No, unfortunately not :/